# Cannot mount GlusterFS from one of the server machines

Tags: glusterfs

Trying to mount glusterfs (4 servers, 2-replication). Running this command:

```
sudo mount -t glusterfs xx.xx.xx.xx:/spark-volume01 /glustermnt
```

Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.

In the logs we have this:

```
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.689276] I [MSGID: 100030] [glusterfsd.c:2318:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.7.7 (args: /usr/sbin/glusterfs --volfile-server=46.4.68.142 --volfile-id=/spark-volume01 /glustermnt)
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.691961] I [MSGID: 101190] [event-epoll.c:632:event_dispatch_epoll_worker] 0-epoll: Started thread with index 1
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695285] E [MSGID: 108040] [afr.c:418:init] 0-spark-volume01-replicate-1: Unable to fetch afr pending changelogs. Is op-version >= 30707? [Invalid argument]
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695299] E [MSGID: 101019] [xlator.c:433:xlator_init] 0-spark-volume01-replicate-1: Initialization of volume 'spark-volume01-replicate-1' failed, review your volfile again
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695307] E [graph.c:322:glusterfs_graph_init] 0-spark-volume01-replicate-1: initializing translator failed
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695311] E [graph.c:661:glusterfs_graph_activate] 0-graph: init failed
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695467] W [glusterfsd.c:1236:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(mgmt_getspec_cbk+0x327) [0x40d9f7] -->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(glusterfs_process_volfp+0x117) [0x408927] -->/usr/sbin/glusterfs(cleanup_and_exit+0x4d) [0x40805d] ) 0-: received signum (0), shutting down
[2016-02-10 15:24:09.695480] I [fuse-bridge.c:5654:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/glustermnt'.
```

All the versions are the same on all machines. Also, this is a new volume with no data on it. Please help!

P.s. Non-replicated distribute volume has been mounted without any problems:

```
xxx@xxxxx:~$ sudo mount -t glusterfs x.x.x.x:/spark-volume-non-replicated /glusterfsmnt-non-replicated
xxx@xxxxx:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
x.x.x.x:/spark-volume-non-replicated  3.4T  1.7T  1.5T  54% /glusterfsmnt-non-replicated
```

Comment: There was a problem with the 3.7.7 release. The offending patch was reverted. 3.7.8 should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like time and date haven't been synchronized for each server. A clock synchronization should help.